# Typescript concept on namespace

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am a little confused on typescript namespacing concept. Coming from Java, I guess namespace spans multiple files, and group them into one namespace.

But in typescript, I can't put namespace into more than 1 file, and import them all. for example:

**spaceConverter.ts**

```
export namespace MySpace {
    export class SpaceConverter1 {

    }
}
```

**timeConverter.ts**

```
export namespace MySpace {
    export class TimeConverter1 {

    }
}
```

then, if I import them like

```
import { MySpace } from './space';
import { MySpace } from './time';
```

I would get an error as duplicate identifier, which is obvious,
but if I put it like

```
export * from './space';
export * from './time';
```

I would get that MySpace has already exported.

My goal is actually very simple.. 
I have multiple classes, which I want to put into "MySpace" group, and let the app import all of them with one name like:

```
import { MySpace } from './myNameSpace';
var space = new MySpace.SpaceConverter1();
var time = new MySpace.TimeConverter1();
```

And I just want the correct form of do this in Typescript.

Thank you

Comment: Remove export in front of namespace.

Comment: you can use modules instead of namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespaces are useful when you are not using modules (export/import). It allows to not pollute the global scope with lots of functions, and prevent overriding existing code in the global scope.

Modules are already isolated so they cannot conflict with other code. Thus, you don't need namespaces in a module. Instead, you can just export classes and functions. If you want to group multiple modules into a single one, you can create a new module that export all other modules. Here's an example:

```
// spaceConverter.ts
export class SpaceConverter1 {
}

// timeConverter.ts
export class TimeConverter1 {
}

// MySpace.ts
export * from './spaceConverter';
export * from './timeConverter';

// main.ts
import * as MySpace from './MySpace';
let converter = new MySpace.SpaceConverter1()
```

Comment: Ah. ok.. That's explains it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need namespace because model itself provides logical grouping.

From [Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html):

> A key feature of modules in TypeScript is that two different modules
>   will never contribute names to the same scope. Because the consumer of
>   a module decides what name to assign it, there’s no need to
>   proactively wrap up the exported symbols in a namespace.
>
> To reiterate why you shouldn’t try to namespace your module contents,
>   the general idea of namespacing is to provide logical grouping of
>   constructs and to prevent name collisions. Because the module file
>   itself is already a logical grouping, and its top-level name is
>   defined by the code that imports it, it’s unnecessary to use an
>   additional module layer for exported objects

Remove namespace from module declaration file and simplify the code in consumer code. Example code:

```
import { SpaceConverter1 } from './space';
import { TimeConverter1 } from './time';
var space = new SpaceConverter1();
var time = new TimeConverter1();
```

You can also rename the module in consumer class as stated above.
Examples:

Rename import

```
import { SpaceConverter1 as SC} from "./space";
let converter = new SC();
```

Import entire module in one variable

```
import * as SC from './space';
let converter = new SC.SpaceConverter1();
```

Comment: Also check red flags at end of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html